# Open source or freeware tools for surveys (like Google Forms) but which allow image upload capability?

Tags: web-apps, open-source, survey

I am looking for a tool like Google Forms which I can use for gathering questionnaire responses from people but with a mechanism for them to upload their photos. It should be able to output the results into an XLS or similar spreadsheet format.

Are there open source tools which I can install and use for this purpose? Or if they are hosted somewhere, but do easy exports, that would be fine as well.

Comment: Is a paid web service OK? ([wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/) in mind)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt "paid" isn't open source or freeware. :)

Comment: @KaranGoel OP says he is OK with hosted tools. Unclear to me whether they have to be open source or not.

Comment: I would assume OP means hosted but freeware.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[LimeSurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org/)**. It's an open source project with a ton of features, and does allow file uploads.

[image]

Comment: Be great to mention if this does support exporting results to csv/xls[x]/other spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports both uploading images and exporting to Excel on the free Individual plan.  Up to 100MB can be stored on this plan.  It is a hosted service, but the forms can be embedded in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Try our product Clappia (https://clappia.com).

You can get the users to upload their files, answer certain questions and then download the responses in the spreadsheet.

Bonus: They work offline if used through the apps.